# Need output in string type

Tags: python-3.x, string, output

I have the input `s` of string. I want to print string `s` in which all the  occurrences of **WUB** are replaced with a white space.

```
s = input()
    print(s.split("WUB"))
```

Input : WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB

but the output I am getting is like this
 : **['', 'WE', 'ARE', '', 'THE', 'CHAMPIONS', 'MY', 'FRIEND', '']**

instead I need output in string format, like this  : **WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the input in the print statement like this

```
s = input()
    print(*s.split("WUB"))
```

Notice `*` before `s.split("WUB")` this gives the desired output.

```
WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND
```

Answer (score 3):

You can join the strings in the list produced by `split` with a space:

```
print(" ".join(s.split("WUB")))
```

You can also just use `replace` instead of `split` + `join`:

```
print(s.replace("WUB", " "))
```

Comment: which of the two method join or replace is faster and space efficient?

Comment: `replace` is better since it's built for this purpose, and it's also faster because it iterates only one time.

Answer (score 0):

Just `join` all elements from your list. See it below:

```
print(" ".join("WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB".split("WUB")).strip())
```